# Apply 3D Luts .cube files into an image using Python

Tags: python, image-processing, lookup-tables

I'm searching for a way to do this, I have looked at OpenCV but at least I could find only ways to apply *1D* Luts files with it (256 long). Does anyone knows how to apply *3D* Luts (64x64x64) to an image using python? thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
$ pip install pillow pillow-lut
```

And then using a random .cube file from an Adobe Photoshop installation:

```
from PIL import Image
from pillow_lut import load_cube_file

lut = load_cube_file("NightFromDay.CUBE")
im = Image.open("image.png")
im.filter(lut).save("image-with-lut-applied.png")
```

Comment: Wow!, this is WAY simpler than i thought. It worked here, thank you!